# How can I append a `div` in a HTML to another HTML's body?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have the following `part.html` file, which contains a `div` and `script`:

```
<div id="GBVX1WkdGsQT1b36AbVC" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Plotly.newPlot("GBVX1WkdGsQT1b36AbVC", {
  "data": [],
  "layout": {},
  "config": {}
});
</script>
```

And I have a `main.html`, which is the file I am rendering on the web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I append the content from `part.html` to `main.html` with using `Javascript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fetch()` to get the text of `part.html`, then set `document.body.innerHTML` to that text. Like this:

*main.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        fetch('part.html') // this can be the URL of any HTML file
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(text => document.body.innerHTML = text);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

*part.html*

```
<!-- Just for demo purposes, can be anything -->
<h1>Test</h1>
```

This can also be easily adapted to use multiple parts by making multiple `fetch()` calls and just doing `document.body.innerHTML += text` each time instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I write the code as you mentioned above, the html file indeed append the part.html's content. But the appended div not show on the web page. What should I do?

Comment: @dfadfdff It's most likely just an issue with the Plotly library because everything else works. I don't know much about Plotly, but make sure that you're including its `<script>` tag and using it correctly. I'd start off with some examples from the documentation.